# Set condition to hide output in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, hidden-fields

I want to set a condition to hide `%%=v(@LastName)=%%` if `%%=v(@FirstName)=%%` is empty/null, is there any function to hide inputs in AMPscript ?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by inputs?  Is this in an email or landing/microsite page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
%%[

var @firstName, @lastName, @greeting
set @firstName = AttributeValue("firstName")
set @lastName = AttributeValue("lastName")

/* verbose */
set @greeting = ""

if not empty(@firstName) then
  set @greeting = concat(", ", @firstName)
endif

if not empty(@firstName) then
  set @greeting = concat(@greeting, " ", @lastName)
endif

/* shorthand */
set @greeting = iif(not empty(@firstName),concat(", ",@firstName),"")=%%%%=iif(not empty(@firstName),concat(" ",@lastName),"")

]%%
Hi%%=v(@greeting)=%%!
```

I tend to write this kind of personalization with [**in-line if statements**](https://ampscript.guide/book/iif) (shorthand above), but sometimes it's more readable to use the more explicit syntax (verbose above).

If you're referring to hiding HTML in a page, you can simply use if-then statements in AMPScript blocks:

```
%%[

  /* AMPScript init-block here */ 

]%%

<!-- other HTML here -->

<body>

%%[ if not empty(@firstName) then ]%%

<h1>%%=v(@lastname)=%%</h1>

%%[ endif ]%%

<!-- other HTML here -->

</body>
```

**Reference**

- [**concat()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/concat)
- [**empty()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/empty)
- [**iif()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/iif)

Comment: can this bee dynamic as well? As in when the first name is entered, the below section hides/unhides instantly?

Comment: It's evaluated before it's sent (or before the page load).  It's not hiding and showing like client-side JavaScript.

Comment: I see, Understand.  Thanks for clearing.  I'm looking for that JS code that can do hide/unhide fields on user input in a cloud page.